# VB Script to search for presence of multiple files in 1 directory

Tags: vbscript, sccm

I would normally use Powershell for this, but for this purpose I need to use VB Script.  I have the following thus far, but it always returns "Files not present" even when the files are, in fact, present.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim InputFile1
InputFile1 = ("C:\%userprofile%\desktop\Entry.lnk")

Dim InputFile2
InputFile2 = ("C:\%userprofile%\desktop\Admin.lnk")

Dim InputFile3
InputFile3 = ("C:\%userprofile%\desktop\Data Admin.lnk")

Dim InputFile4
InputFile4 = ("C:\%userprofile%\desktop\Verification.lnk")

If (FSO.FileExists(InputFile1)) And (FSO.FileExists(InputFile2)) And (FSO.FileExists(InputFile3)) And (FSO.FileExists(InputFile4)) Then
    WScript.Echo ("Present")
    Else
        WScript.Echo ("Files Not Present")
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
```

Comment: You have to expand the environment variable `%userprofile%`

Comment: @GeertBellekens I admit I don't know VBScript (only VBA) but I don't see how that target answers the question at all. The target's problem is apparently that OP didn't use a variable after assigning a value to it. This question appears to be a case of OP not using the right environment path.

Comment: @TylerH it's to do with the explanation of how environment variables like `%userprofile%` need to be expanded first and cannot be used directly as a path in FSO.

Comment: @user692942 I see; I've revised the answer on the target to make it clear what the issue is; it now more clearly answers this question, too.

Answer (score -1):

The cause is that `"%UserProfile%"` is literal - meaning it is literally part of your string. The only way to get that part of your path is to pass it through the `Wscript.Shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")` and concatenate `"\Desktop\"`. I would just use `Wscript.Shell.SpecialFolders` and it will have the user profile as part of the path when you choose `"Desktop"`. Below is what I would do but there are other ways. I don't really create variables if I can just pass the method call. So this keeps is short and sweet -- just my opinion.

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO
Dim FilePath

Wscript.Shell.SpecialFolders

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FilePath = FSO.GetFolder(Wscript.Shell.SpecialFolders("DESKTOP")) & "\"
    If FSO.FileExists(FilePath & "Entry.lnk") And FSO.FileExists(FilePath & "Admin.lnk") And _
        FSO.FileExists(FilePath & "Data Admin.lnk") And FSO.FileExists(FilePath & "Verification.lnk") Then
        Wscript.echo "Present"
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "Files Not Present"
    End If
    
 Set WSH = Nothing
 Set FSO = Nothing
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use an array to store the link names :

```
ArrFiles = Array("Entry.lnk","Admin.lnk","Data Admin.lnk","Verification.lnk")
```

and use the variable Desktop like this :

```
Desktop = CreateObject("wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\"
```

And the code becomes like :

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO,Desktop,ArrFiles,File
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Desktop = CreateObject("wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\"
ArrFiles = Array("Entry.lnk","Admin.lnk","Data Admin.lnk","Verification.lnk")
For Each File in ArrFiles
    If FSO.FileExists(Desktop & File) Then
        WScript.Echo File & " is Present on" & vbcrlf & Desktop
    Else
        WScript.Echo File & " is Not Present on " & vbcrlf & Desktop
    End If
Next
Wscript.Quit
```